# how to convert the string of numbers into integers preserving the same digital numbers?

Tags: python

How to convert the string of numbers into integers preserving the same digital numbers?
for example:

```
ml = ['076']
print int(ml[0])
76
```

but i require the result as 076

Comment: WHAT ?! You want to *store* integer with leading zeros? Really ?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: You'd have to store the string length separately, and then later reformat the integer back to a string with enough padding. Integer values have no padding, they are just numbers.

Comment: do you mean they actually stands for octal numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ml = ['076']
print "%03d" % int(ml[0])
076
```

That's useful if say you want to perform a calculation and then print the result with leading zeros:

```
ml = ['076']
print "%03d" % (int(ml[0]) / 2) 
038
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: not.

A bit longer: `076` is *not* an integer, so it will never be the result of converting anything to an integer.

If you want to *present* an integer as a string (e.g. with leading zeroes), then do it when *presenting* it. But always realize that that string(!) representation is *not* an actual integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ml = ['076']
g = [ml[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(ml), 2)]
print(g)
```